# Regular expression to avoid special characters and should not start with numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

What regular expression can I use to not allow special characters and make certain it does not begin with numbers.

I'm using `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` which is filtering out special characters. How can I make sure it does not start with numbers in regex itself.

Also i'm using **ng-pattern** of angular with my input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

This should do it.

Try this if you want to have one or two words.

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks @vks. Is there a possibility to check only two words allowed in input box with same regex?. But i'm currently finding it using split and finding array length to be 2.

Comment: Yes @vks, thats what i mean "User name" string is valid

Comment: @ram `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` Try this.This will allow one or two words.If you want only two words use `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ also gives error when adding two words. Actually when i give space after typing first word it does not show error, but when i start typing second word it triggers error.

Comment: i checked the above link. /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ It works in that page but in my code if i give a blank space and type second word, it shows error though both the strings are valid. :(

Comment: @ram have you used the regex in the link.Coz you have posted a differnert regex here

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
^[^\W0-9_][^\W_]+$
```

If Spaces are permitted

```
^[^\W0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$
```

If you're not trying to match the whole string, you can remove ^ and $ which match start and end respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]/
```

to make sure your input is only starting with a letter (non-digit and non-special character).